# Not working checkbox checked

Tags: jquery

When i add to div values from input, i need to click on checkbox so its alert("checked"). My code not working correctly. Can u please tell me what i've been doing wrong.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <p>Title:</p>
        <input type="text" id="title">
        <p>Link:</p>
        <input type="text" id="link">
    </form>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="content" style="margin-top:50px"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn-success").click(function(){
        var  title_val = $("#title").val();
        var  link_val = $("#link").val();
        $(".content").append('<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><ol class="breadcrumb"><h4>'+title_val+'</h4><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></ol><a href="http://'+link_val+'" class="thumbnail"></a></div>');
    });

    $("#checkbox").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert("Checked");
        }
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/taw92uzz/)

Comment: Viktor the first reason why you code was not working was always use on if your u r adding html dynamically after that other was never use id if your adding multiple elements for same id always prefer class for that.

Comment: @Gaurav Events do not work without delegation on dynamically added elements. I have no clue who voted your answer up. Seriously, the quality of StackOverflow has become down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox is dynamically added. So you need to delegate the event handler to already existing element, and make sure not to give same `ID`s:

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkbox", function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
});
```

Change your appending function to use class instead of ID.

```
$(".content").append('<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><ol class="breadcrumb"><h4>'+title_val+'</h4><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></ol><a href="http://'+link_val+'" class="thumbnail"></a></div>');
```

Comment: i am agree with you you have answered properly

Comment: you answer is best i have just shared what i thought

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Add Class on the checkbox then is jquery use this code :

```
$('.chk').live('click',function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert("Checked");
        }
    })
```

Check on this link [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ken94tz6/3/)

Comment: Please add the concept of event delegation.

Comment: 1. Your code is not same as in fiddle. 2. Using `.live()`? Nice. That's dead long back.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/taw92uzz/1/)**

```
$('.content').on('click', "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: IDs cannot be duplicated. Basic rule.

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, you are right. but I did not notice that It was possible to add muliple checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Use this code
$(document).on('click', '#checkbox' , function(){ 
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert("Checked");
  } 
});
```